How should I show that solutions with angular frequency $\omega$ can be expressed as a Fourier series?
Homework problem: Consider the equation $\ddot{x}+x+\epsilon(\alpha x^2\operatorname{sgn}(x)+\beta x^3)=0, 0<\epsilon<<1, \alpha>0, \beta>0$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants, and the signum function, $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$, is defined by $\operatorname{sgn}(x)=1$ for $x>0$, $\operatorname{sgn}(x)=0$ for $x=0$ and $\operatorname{sgn}(x)=-1$ for $x<0$. With initial condition $x(0)=0$, show that solutions with angular frequency $\omega$ can be expressed as a Fourier series of the form $x(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}B_{2k-1}\sin((2k-1)\omega t)=B_{1}\sin\omega t+B_{3}\sin 3\omega t+...$.
Here's my work: Proof:
So far I've got that the potential energy function $V(x)$ of the system is $V(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}+\epsilon(\frac{\alpha x^3\operatorname{sgn}(x)}{3}+\frac{\beta x^4}{4})$ and that system is $\dot{x}=y, \dot{y}=-x-\epsilon(\alpha x^2\operatorname{sgn}(x)+\beta x^3)$ for $0<\epsilon<<1, \alpha>0, \beta>0$ where $\beta$ and $\alpha$ are constants.
What should I do from here in order to use the given initial condition of $x(0)=0$ to show that solutions with angular frequency $\omega$ can be expressed as a Fourier series of the given form from the problem?
