How should I find $\rho(\eta)$ with this initial condition?
Homework problem: Solve the differential equation of $\frac{d\rho}{d\eta}=\rho(1-2\rho^2)$ with the initial condition $\rho(0)=\frac{1}{4}a^2$.
Here's my work:
I've applied the method of separating variables and obtained $\int\frac{d\rho}{\rho(1-2\rho^2)}=\int d\eta$. To integrate $\int\frac{d\rho}{\rho(1-2\rho^2)}$, I used the method of partial fraction decomposition and got $\frac{1}{\rho(1-2\rho^2)}=\frac{A}{\rho}+\frac{B\rho}{1-2\rho^2}=\frac{A(1-2\rho^2)+B\rho^2}{\rho(1-2\rho^2)}$ where $A(1-2\rho^2)+B\rho^2=1\implies A-2A\rho^2+B\rho^2=1\implies A+(B-2A)\rho^2=1$ such that $A=1$ and $B-2A=0\implies B=2$.
Hence, $\frac{1}{\rho(1-2\rho^2)}=\frac{1}{\rho}+\frac{2\rho}{1-2\rho^2}$ and so $\int\frac{d\rho}{\rho(1-2\rho^2)}=\int\frac{d\rho}{\rho}+\int\frac{2\rho}{1-2\rho^2}d\rho=\ln\lvert \rho \rvert-\frac{1}{2}\ln\lvert 1-2\rho^2 \rvert+C$.
Now we have $\ln\lvert \rho \rvert-\frac{1}{2}\ln\lvert 1-2\rho^2 \rvert=\eta+C\implies ln\lvert \rho \rvert-\ln\lvert \sqrt{1-2\rho^2} \rvert=\eta+C\implies \ln\lvert \frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1-2\rho^2}} \rvert=\eta+C\implies \frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1-2\rho^2}}=Ce^{\eta}.$
Observe that $\sqrt{1-2\rho^2}=\frac{\rho}{Ce^{\eta}}\implies 1-2\rho^2=\frac{\rho^2}{Ce^{2\eta}}\implies 1=\frac{\rho^2}{Ce^{2\eta}}+2\rho^2\implies \frac{\rho^2}{Ce^{2\eta}}+\frac{2\rho^2(Ce^{2\eta})}{Ce^{2\eta}}=1\implies \rho^2+2\rho^2(Ce^{2\eta})=Ce^{2\eta}\implies \rho^2(1+Ce^{2\eta})=Ce^{2\eta}.$
Thus, $\rho^2=\frac{Ce^{2\eta}}{1+Ce^{2\eta}}\implies \rho=\pm\sqrt{\frac{Ce^{2\eta}}{1+Ce^{2\eta}}}.$
From here, I know I have to use the initial condition $\rho(0)=\frac{1}{4}a^2$ but before I do so, I want to know if everything is right/correct in my work shown above. Also, is the answer I got correct? Is that the correct $\rho(\eta)$?

For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. This should not be the only tag for a question, and should not be used to circumvent site policies regarding duplication.

It looks fine to me, but note that you can always check your solution by plugging it into your original differential equation. By the way, it is easier to find the $C$ corresponding to the initial condition from the equation
$$ \ln\lvert \frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1-2\rho^2}} \rvert=\eta+C$$
rather than the explicit form of $\rho(\eta)$.

Yes, I got the right/correct answer. Thank you for the help! May you take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5015022/how-should-i-show-that-solutions-with-angular-frequency-omega-can-be-expresse ?

Please strive not to answer solution verification questions that are off-topic (missing required context).
